# iOS push notifications not working with PHP server

Tags: php, ios, push-notification

I have the ports open and the certificate created and stored in the server. I use the following code:

```
    public function send_mobile_notification_request()
    {
        // Put your device token here (without spaces):
        $deviceToken = '0A01703BDB53E5852F65D0B651BC79003ADDB6B3497D456EF63B6402E07C0475';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
        $passphrase = '';


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        $ctx = stream_context_create();
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'pushcert.pem');
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
        $fp = stream_socket_client(
            'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
            $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

        if (!$fp)
            exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

        echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
        $body['aps'] = array(
            'content-available' => '1',
        );

// Encode the payload as JSON
        $payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
        $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

        if (!$result)
            echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
        else
            echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
        fclose($fp);
 }
```

What I get is the message 'Message successfully delivered' So apparently it works but I am not receiving anything. I also check with some push notifications sender programs to check that the certificate is working properly and there I get the notifications. The worst thing is that I am not getting any error so I don't know what to do to solve it.

Comment: You are connection to `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com` are you sure that you are using a development certificate and production?

Comment: I can recommended you this APN library which i used: https://github.com/immobiliare/ApnsPHP   It has well formatted exception handlers, will help you to find whats wrong.

Comment: I tested with both  gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com and  gateway.push.apple.com  just in case but I created a development certificate

Comment: Can you do a echo $result at the end?

Comment: 'Connected to APNS 97' is what I get when I make an echo of $result